# Redirect and refresh page on form submission in React frontend

Tags: reactjs

I have a form which when submitted creates a new entry in my MongoDB Database.

Upon doing this though, I want this new entry to display on my 'redirect' page. However - instead of 'refreshing' the page, it simply redirects, and the page appears the same as it did when it was last navigated away from.

So my question is, how do I re-factor my code so that on form submission the redirect also refreshes the redirect page?

Here's my submit code:

```
  onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post("/api/submitDebt", {
      creditCard: this.state.creditCardToggled,
      personalLoan: this.state.personalLoanToggled,
      provider: this.state.provider,
      balance: this.state.balance,
      limit: this.state.limit,
      monthly: this.state.monthly,
      interest: this.state.interest,
      borrowed: this.state.borrowed
    })

    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
```

I'm assuming it's because it's 'this.props.history', so it returns the original page. What's the best way for me to refactor this redirect to also reload the page on form submit?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: The dashboard component which renders the form submission. I’m doing this on mobile so hopefully works okay!

```
class IndividualDebts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      debts: []
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("/api/fetchDebtCards")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ debts: response.data })
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }

  render() {

    const fetchDebts = this.state.debts.map (debt => {

      return (

       <IndividualDebtCard key={debt._id}
        picture={(`../images/${debt.provider}.jpg`)}
        provider={debt.provider}
        type={debt.creditCard === 'true' ? "Credit Card" : "Personal Loan" }
        balance={debt.balance}
        limit={debt.creditCard === 'true' ? debt.limit : debt.borrowed}
        monthly={debt.monthly}
        interest={debt.interest} />

            )
        })

    return (
      <div>
        <section className="individual-debts-section">
          <div className="individual-debts-container">

              {this.state.debts.length === 0 ?

                <div className="no-debts-container">

                <h3>There are no debts linked yet. Why not try adding one now?</h3>

                <ActionButton link="link-debt" type="button" text="Link debt" />

                </div>  : <div className="individual-debts-card-container">{fetchDebts}</div>  }

          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default IndividualDebts;
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Added my route with React Router for Dashboard component.

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Comment: Could you share the `dashboard component` implementation?

Comment: I’ve added it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already loading the data on mount as you said, I see 2 possible issues:

The first one, is that you are not waiting for the async request to return before redirecting. For that purpose, simply dd an `await`:

```
onSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    await axios.post("/api/submitDebt", {
      creditCard: this.state.creditCardToggled,
      personalLoan: this.state.personalLoanToggled,
      provider: this.state.provider,
      balance: this.state.balance,
      limit: this.state.limit,
      monthly: this.state.monthly,
      interest: this.state.interest,
      borrowed: this.state.borrowed
    })

    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
```

The other issue is that you are not unmounting and mounting the component on each route change. Try to change your route decleration to this:

```
<Route path="/dashboard" render={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
```

When you use `render` instead of `component`, the route will rerender `Dashboard` on every pathanme change to `'/dashboard'`, meanning your `componentDidMount` will run each time.

Comment: Yep, the data fetches fine - it’s linked on componentDidMount. That’s not the issue, it’s that I have to refresh the page to activate that after the form submission. When the form is submitted, it just returns the original dashboard page without the new entry. I’d like to refactor the code so that it refreshes automatically, and so it’s not done manually. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you please post the code of how you defined your route?

Comment: Hey - do you mean my React Router or my dashboard component? :-)

Comment: The code in which you defined `'/dashboard'` to render  `<Dashboard />`

Comment: I meant a line that should look something like `<Route path="/dashboard" ..... />`

Comment: Added that now - sorry

Comment: Thank you for the edit - this works. It works just with async / await on SubmitDebt too, but this is a good answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I feel the issue is you are not waiting for the axios call (asynchronous) to finish before navigating to the dashboard. Maybe try using async/await something like:

```js
  onSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    await axios.post("/api/submitDebt", {
      creditCard: this.state.creditCardToggled,
      personalLoan: this.state.personalLoanToggled,
      provider: this.state.provider,
      balance: this.state.balance,
      limit: this.state.limit,
      monthly: this.state.monthly,
      interest: this.state.interest,
      borrowed: this.state.borrowed
    })

    this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use then/catch block like so:

```js
  onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    await axios.post("/api/submitDebt", {
      creditCard: this.state.creditCardToggled,
      personalLoan: this.state.personalLoanToggled,
      provider: this.state.provider,
      balance: this.state.balance,
      limit: this.state.limit,
      monthly: this.state.monthly,
      interest: this.state.interest,
      borrowed: this.state.borrowed
    })
    .then(()=> this.props.history.push('/dashboard'))
    .catch(()=> console.log("error in posting data"));

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it works spot on. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class component you can try to fetch your data when the '/dashboard' component will be mounted

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetchData()
}
```